Reducing duplicates in and size of dependency storage across multiple projects
I am currently working with a new program that has been developed to store all of its dependencies in a folder called 'Product'. I'm sort of new to .csproj files so I'm figuring this out as I go. I have been tasked with reducing the size of this Product folder. The main issue is that there are dozens of duplicate folders that contain some or all of the same DLLs. The solution has multiple projects under it that use a lot of the same DLLs. Is there a way to point these ProjectReferences and the project build to store and call these dependencies from the same location, as to avoid duplicates?

If I understand your question. There are project cross referencing to each other. Now you want a centralized dll folder from which you can you reference instead of depending on the projects. That way you will have a single dll folder with latest code dll and will able to save some space.
